# uploading file from Access 2010

Tags: file, vba, upload

I have a Access 2010 frontend database + MySQL as backend. So far it is working fine. I would like to upload document and decided to save on the server rather than on the Database. My first question is, how do I upload file from access frontend to the remote server/location?

I was thinking, maybe store the data on the database and use some kind of triggers or script which reads the blob file from database and saves on the server as well as fills the file path into another column.

is there any easier way to upload files from access frontend to a remote server? I am using MySQL server as backend.

thank you in advance

Comment: Is the remote server/location a Windows file share that your users have access to anyway?

Comment: its a linux server in the cloud and completely invisible for the users. Access 2010 frontend uses mySQL driver to connect to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SFTP with Putty**

This might help you - it's a great example using Putty on the Windows machine to communicate over SFTP with the Linux server using VBA: [SFTP upload with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754928/sftp-upload-with-vba)

You would need to install putty on each Windows machine that uses Access and ensure that the appropriate rights are in place on the Linux server.

**Custom Add-In**

You could use .NET to create an add-in for access to transfer the file to the server over sockets, but this would require you to write a server-side application to listen for requests.  You would have complete freedom over how you implement it at the cost of added complexity for yourself as the developer.

You would need to:

- Create an add-in using Visual Studio (or other .NET IDE)
- Add this into your Access application and use the API you've built.
- Create a server-side application to listen to it (this could be a simple Python application)

**SMTP Approach**

If you want to be creative you could email the file to your own mock SMTP server using Access' CDO functionality: [Sending emails with Access](http://www.rondebruin.nl/cdo.htm)

Again, you would have to create a handler application to handle the SMTP protocol, but I'm sure there are some great examples out there.

**HTTP Approach**

You could even encode the file and send it over HTTP to a simple PHP server in a simple POST request: [Example web request with Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577309/ms-access-perform-post-webrequest) You would need to encode the file to base64 or something or file a way of handling file uploads.

**Conclusion**

As you can see, the easiest approach by far is using Putty, but there are some interesting custom approaches you could take.

I'd say using either SMTP or HTTP would be suitable but that depends how easily you could set up the server-side handler. There may be existing SMTP emulators out there that you could use to handle receiving and managing files.

Comment: Thank you tony. Is there any independent way? I do not want to ask all our customers to install putty. Ideally I would like to see the upload progress too. So i was thinking something modern and more accurate.

Comment: @krish As you can see, there are a number of ways to do it independently, but you'd need to get creative. There may still be some simpler approaches using Microsoft's native functionality so please do keep looking.

Comment: thank you for the great answer. I will check them all. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

this might help someone.

I have used Chilkat FTP activeX component and its working fine. Chilkat provides prewritten code just copied from his website and everything is fine. Although I could not find how to show the transferring progress.

regards
krish